# Language Features Not Translatable into Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

Haskell is said to be a pure language because the language features are directly translatable into lambda calculus.

My question is: for languages considered to be non-pure functional languages (e.g. Scala, OCaml), which aspects of those languages are not translatable into lambda calculus?

Comment: Lambda calculus is Turing complete, but not [Tetris complete](http://everything2.com/title/Tetris+complete)

Comment: Haskell, Scala and Lambda calculus are all Turing-complete, so we *know* that there are computable cross-compilers. What do you mean by "directly translatable"?

Comment: @Raphael Turing-complete is a rather weak characterization of languages. For example, the lambda calculus is Turing complete, but we certainly can't do IO in it, like we can with Scala.

Answer (score 4):

That's not what "pure" means. Pure means, generally, that there is no mutable state, and no way to interact with the outside world (i.e. IO).

Haskell is *not* "directly translatable" (what translation between language features really means needs to be defined fist, but let's ignore that for now) into either the untyped or simply-typed lambda calculus. There are many features that prevent it from being so, but a good example is polymorphism: there is no polymorphic identity function in the simply-typed lambda calculus.

Instead, Haskell and SML are actually derived from the Hindley-Milner type system, which is an *extension* of the simply-typed lambda calculus with polymorphism and type-constructors (aka higher-kinded types). Hindley-Milner has the nice property that type inference is decidable without *any* type annotations.